# How to order by value using Firebase Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to order my data based on value amount. Basically a leaderboard with highest score on top. I do not have trouble retrieving the data, however, there is a problem with the ordering.

```
"NtkLF86dVPfjBI1VioG7w1dqSan2" : {
      "Taps" : 1439,
    },
"XAnGrikzUAgQCVJmo3n4mGvjhzf2" : {
      "Taps" : 2000
    }
```

For example, I want the second user to be displayed on top since they have a higher score. When I do:

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("User").queryOrdered(byChild: "Taps").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Get user value
                let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
                //let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
                //let taps = value?["taps"] as? Int ?? 0

                print (value)
            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
```

It doesn't order by value. Am I missing something? Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just pull them from firebase instead of creating a dictionary?

Comment: How would I go about doing so? @Mr.Xcoder

Comment: Yes, how would I go about putting it into a dictionary? The same way I did let value = .... NSDictionary? @Mr.Xcoder

Comment: I followed that tutorial. But it did not let me do it. I even created a separate structure called "Leaderboard" with just UIDs and the score. And tried to pull it using the same method just with orderbyvalue and .indexOn. Still nothing. :/ @Mr.Xcoder maybe you can find something that I missed?

Comment: Okay thank you @Mr.Xcoder